# IntegrityError in Django Custom User Model which doesn't go away even after deleting all migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I keep getting this error whenever I tried to create a post. I have gone through all similar questions on this platform and made several adjustments but the error still occurs.

> IntegrityError at /api/admin/create/
> NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id
> Request Method:   POST
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/create/

Below is my cusstom user model:

```
class NewUser(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email_address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(_('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'user_name']
```

Below is my custom manager for the custome user model:

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True')
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True')

        user = self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields)
     
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, first_name=first_name, **other_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Below is my serializer class for the custome user model:

```
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

    
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password', 'first_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Below is my view :

```
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format='json'):

        reg_serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if reg_serializer.is_valid():
            newuser = reg_serializer.save()
            if newuser:
                json = reg_serializer.data
                return Response(json, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(reg_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is the post view to which the endpoint "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/create/" is connected:

```
class CreatePost(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

**First Edit: Here is the Post Model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    class PostObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status = 'published')
            
    options = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )

    post_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1, related_name="postcategory")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField(null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(_("image"), upload_to=upload_to, default='posts/default.jpg')
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='published')
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='published')
    objects = models.Manager()      #default manager
    postobjects = PostObjects()     #custom manager


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-published',)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Second Edit: here is what I have in the settings file:**

## Custom user Model

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.NewUser"
```

**THIRD EDIT: This is the View and Serializer I'm using to create Posts:**

**View**

```
class CreatePost(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_id', 'category', 'title', 'author', 'content', 'excerpt', 'slug', 'status', 'photo')
```

Comment: You have to delete all the migrations and also the database. Did you also delete the database?

Comment: Yes, I deleted migrations and databases. I did that several times.

Answer (score 1):

The Post model needs a user as an author, but no author is being passed. This results in a "NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id" error because the author_id cannot be null. To resolve this, please provide the View and Serializer you are using to create Posts. This will allow me to demonstrate how to assign the current user or the user making the request as the author, assuming that is your intention.

**EDIT:**

Overwrite the create method of your serializer to set the author to the request user:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().create(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_id', 'category', 'title', 'author', 'content', 'excerpt', 'slug', 'status', 'photo')
```

Comment: I have done that. Please check the third edit of my question.

Comment: I will edit my answer then

Comment: I have overwritten the create method using the code you provided but I got another ValueError and TypeError. But after reading the documentation, I was able able to solve it by just overwriting the create method with these two lines of code:
```
def create(self, validated_data):
        return Post(**validated_data)
```
Thanks a lot, I couldn't have done that before.

Comment: Does that cause a post to be created?

Comment: Yes. That solved everything. Although, according to the documentation, having return Post.objects.create(**validated_data) is more appropriate than just return Post(**validated_data). Using the former gives me the IntegrityError again, but using the latter does not. I don't really know what's happening. Something might be wrong somewhere.

Comment: See [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

Answer (score 0):

could you add Post Model to your data ?
maybe I can help if I see it...

Comment: I've done that! t

Comment: I'm still waiting for your response bro. The code really gives me headache.